# How to return the class of an element?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the class of a `td` table because I want skip the content to save.. But I'm stuck on this and in the documentation I can't find how to do this.
For example:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="h1">ONE</td>
    <td class="h2">TWO</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In this table I want to grab only the content of `h1 td class` and skip `h2 content`

How I can achieve this? Actually I can get the content like this way:

```
foreach ($table[0]->find('tr') as $row) 
{
    foreach ($row->find('td') as $td) 
    {
        echo $td->plaintext . " | ";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

but in the second foreach I want execute a condition like:

```
if(td-> somemethod that return the class == h2){continue;}else{do stuff...}
```

Ideas?

Comment: you would use the php DOM object http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and use probably getAttribute to parse the html of the page (assuming its coming from a curl source so loaded in to a variable?)

Comment: so this library doesn't support yet a method to get the class of a specific html element?

Comment: A `<td class="???">` is an attribute of the `td` tag

Comment: Class is an attribute of the DOM tag td as RiggsFolly said. tbh the better would be to have your td tags with a name or id attribute then you can use the getElementbyId etc

Comment: @JayBlanchard I didn't mention javascript...... its all php.

Comment: @JayBlanchard erm.... no its not http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Comment: *smacks forehead* My apologies @Dave, I was stuck in JS mode.

Comment: @JayBlanchard nps it happens from time to time, besides php's DOM object is massively underused by most people so not many people seem to know it that well anyway.

Comment: @Bender can you accept the answer if it worked rather than leave the question in limbo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `class` is an attribute it would appear that you want this

```
if ($td->getAttribute('class') == 'h2'){continue;}else{/*do stuff...*/}
```

or since you want it when `class` = `h1`, this condition makes more sense

```
if ($td->getAttribute('class') == 'h1'){/*do stuff...*/}
```

[DOMElement::getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)